# laravel8 phpunit test is calling original user model instead of mock user model

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Here my controller  that have a user model in contructor

```php
class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public $user = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new User();
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(UserIndexGetRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $userList = $this->user->getAllUsers($request);

            //is_dropdown will be passed from client call when you want to load or get all dropdown options without pagination
            if (!empty($request->is_dropdown)) {
                $userList = new UserAllDataCollection($userList);
            } else {
                $userList = new UserCollection($userList);
            }
            
            //return error response if no records founds
            if ($userList->isEmpty()) {
                return $this->sendError(__('users.no_data_found'));
            }

            //user list response
            return $this->sendResponse($userList, __('users.all_users_list'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //return error response on exception
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my php unit test case  for the above controller and which should use my mock model user and than it should call `getAllUsers` method but instead it calls original `getAllUsers` model

```php
class RouteValidateTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    public function test_loginUrl()
    {
        $mockrequest = $this->partialMock(UserIndexGetRequest::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('passes')->andReturn(true);
        });

        $mockuserModel = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();
        $mockuserModel->shouldReceive('getAllUsers')
            ->once()
            ->with($mockrequest)
            ->andReturn(true);

        $this->app->instance(User::class, $mockuserModel);

        $response = $this->call('GET', '/api/v1/user', ['name' => 'laaa']);

        dd($response);

        $this->assertEquals(302, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Still while executing the code my mock model is not getting called instead original user model is getting called. I have tried many ways but none worked for me  can any help I'm totally stuck in this

Comment: Have you tried `$response = $this->actingAs($mockuserModel)->call(...)`?

Comment: You never mock requests and models, you must fake the data using a factory and a database, and call the real endpoint...

Comment: @Ross_102 it does not work

Comment: @matiaslauriti ye your right but  for the unit case specially instructed to avoid use stub,so trying luck on different approach

Answer (score -1):

here in your code you have used :

```
$this->app->instance(User::class, $mockuserModel);
```

this technique is called laravel service container : [here is documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container)

for you instance() method to work you need to resolve you User class **and not create User object with new** ,so in your controller's constructor change this :

```
$this->user = new User();
```

to this :

```
$this->user = resolve(User::class);
```

I hope it will work .

Comment: You are right, but still, NEVER mock models, there are a lot of "behind the scenes" stuff going on that you would either have to mock or you could be loosing that, so when the real code runs, something else could happen and you are not aware of that, so NEVER mock models nor requests/form requests

Comment: @Ata barzegar it work, but is there is another way to work around this as above solution is brining code changes

Comment: I really don't have other idea , but as 
@matiaslauriti  says it is not a good idea to mock models in your tests . 
so try to use factories .  
but the problem is that why you try to mock your model? . please explain it .

Comment: @Ata barzegar
Actually, for the above test case, I just need to pass the random parameter and check the response in return for this i need to avoid the DB hit

Comment: if you want to test a form request, you still use a feature test and directly hit the URL and expect an error back. There is not really a "I want to avoid a database hit", if it happens, it happens, but if you have nothing, that's it! I don't see why it is an issue, could you explain more?

Comment: @matiaslauriti
The application is basically developed to handle API call. So we want to create a small unit test that can be done in a very quick manner, Making DB connection and running the test is taking a lot more time than expected and it become our job very slow for deployment, That why we are focusing to wrap up the unit test in shorter and quick
Anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: Well, the only thing that comes to my mind is that the team is not correctly testing. If you don't want to hit the database and stuff, just don't use traits like `RefreshDatabase` nor run any seeders. Can't you do that?